# Transform output file E:\NewJoystick\mavlink\build\libs\ndk-libs.jar does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There is no mavlink/build/libs libs file does not exist also ndk-libs.jar does not exist too! How can i solve this problem? I changed paths and also paths are correct i think but i made sdk configuration and synchronization, cleaned project rebuilded project there is still same error. Can anyone help please?

here is my local.properties file code

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
gst.dir=C\:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\gstolayi
```

and here is my build.gradle module:mavlink

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        ndk{
            moduleName 'mavlink_native'
        }
    }
    sourceSets{
        main{
            jni.srcDirs=[]
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}
tasks.withType(Exec){
    environment['PATH']=System.getenv('PATH')+':/usr/local/bin'
    def ndkDir = System.getenv('NDK_HOME')
    if (ndkDir == null){
        def localProperties = new Properties()
        localProperties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        ndkDir = localProperties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
    }
    if (ndkDir == null){
        throw new GradleException('no NDK_SDK directory specified, Add ndk.dir=<PATH_TO_NDK> to local.properties or define NDK_HOME environment variable')
    }
    environment['NDK_HOME']=ndkDir
}

dependencies{
    implementation fileTree(dir:'libs',include:['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir:"$buildDir/libs",include:'ndk-libs')
    implementation files("$buildDir/libs/ndk-libs.jar")
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkLibsToJar
    }
    task ndkLibsToJar(type:Zip,dependsOn:'ndkBuild',description:'create a jar of the native libs'){
        destinationDir new File(buildDir,'libs')
        baseName 'ndk-libs'
        extension 'jar'
        from(new File(buildDir,'libs')){
            include '**/*.so'
        }
        into'lib/'
    }
    task ndkBuild (type:Exec,description:'compile JNI source via NDK'){
        commandLine environment['NDK_HOME']+'/ndk-build','NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build','APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    implementation project(':threadwrapper')
    implementation project(':connectionlistener')
}
```

Comment: post your code not image of the code

Comment: OK sorry, i edited the post.